# deleting children from XML variable

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

Having a problem manipulating some XML with ActionScript in Flex 4.6

Here's my XML variable contents:

```
var employeeXML:XML contains

    <salesforce>
       <salesman>
          <id>42</id>
          <territory>OJAI</territory>
       </salesman>
    </salesforce>
```

Here's my ActionScript:

```
idToMerge = "42";
delete employeeXML.salesman.(id == idToMerge);
```

Here's my error:

```
 TypeError: Error #1119
```

What's the proper way to delete the  who's  is 42 from an XML variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to locate the node which is having id= "42" and then delete the whole node. Following code will do that.

```
idToMerge:String = "42";

employeeXML.salesman.((id==idToMerge) && (delete parent().children()  [valueOf().childIndex()]));
```